# MongoDB aggregate $lookup with _ID's from array

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have two collections in MongoDB: "carts" and another "products"

Carts:

```
[{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "62af0fefebc0b42a875c7df1"
  },
  "uuid": "6ca05ae0-522a-4db3-b380-2d2330ee1e27",
  "cartitems": [
    "62a0b24680cc2891148daf7b",
    "62a7339d91d01868921afa0a",
    "62a72f7191d01868921afa08",
    "62a7330291d01868921afa09"
  ],
  "created": "2022-06-19T14:00:47.846958537+02:00[Europe/Brussels]",
  "lastupdate": "2022-06-19T14:01:06.15165564+02:00[Europe/Brussels]"
},
{...},
{...}]
```

products:

```
[{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "62a0b24680cc2891148daf7b"
  },
  "name": "Product1",
  "created": "2022-06-11T09:41:54.461308647+02:00[Europe/Brussels]",
  "category": "Workshops",
  "pricein": "28900",
  "lastupdate": "2022-06-17T16:09:53.385655474+02:00[Europe/Brussels]"
},
{...},
{...}]
```

I would like to use Aggregate:

```
db.carts.aggregate([
  { $match: { uuid: "6ca05ae0-522a-4db3-b380-2d2330ee1e27" } },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "products",
      localField: "cartitems",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "output"
    }
  }
])
```

This is not working because **localField: "cartitems"** should be converted:

```
"$addFields": {
        "convertedIdStr": {
           "$toString": "$cartitems"
        }
```

But I don't manage to convert because cartitems is an array.
Any help would be great, Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hello Mohit,

I need all the products with their details so I can display the contents of the shopping cart. In the "carts" collection I only save the ID's of the products, so I can work with latest price and productdetails every time the shopping cart is shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`$lookup` with pipeline](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-subqueries-on-a-joined-collection). In `$lookup` pipeline stage, add `$match` stage by filtering the (converted to string) product's `_id` is in `cartitems` (array) variable.

```
db.carts.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      uuid: "6ca05ae0-522a-4db3-b380-2d2330ee1e27"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "products",
      let: {
        cartitems: "$cartitems"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $in: [
                {
                  $toString: "$_id"
                },
                "$$cartitems"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "output"
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Dy5g8Oanfah)

Comment: One little extra question, where can I limit the fields (or include only certain fields) returned in the output?

Comment: Hi, yes, you can add `$project` stage in `$lookup` pipeline.